# Send audio over WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm implementig `getUserMedia()` to record audio messages. I want to record the audio and then pass it using websocket to another peer. How I can accomplish this?I've searched on SO and I've found only some interesting question, but nothing that can guide me to a working solution. I'm using Pusher API for the websocket part of my app. 
Here is the code I'm testing.

```
$(document).on("click", ".audio-chat",function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  var channel = $('input[name="channelName"]').val();
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  })
  .then(function(stream){
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start();
    console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
    console.log("recorder started");

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
      console.log(chunks);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
      console.log("recorder stopped");
      var blob = new Blob(chunks, {'type':'audio/webm; codecs=opus'});
      //console.log(blob);
      chunks = [];
      const audioUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var data = {channel:channel,message:audioUrl,socketId:socketId}
      $.post('api/message.php', data);
    }, 10000);
  });
});
```

Comment: I've not mentioned PHP in the question

Comment: then why tag it?

Comment: Hi mate, do you want to send a file or a stream ?

Comment: Try this backend is on node but frontend will remain same https://stackoverflow.com/a/50976085/4518930

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I just want to send the recorded audio (stream) without saving it on the server. I know that there is webRTC but it will consume a lot of resources of my pusher api quota for signaling so I prefere to use websockets

Comment: @AdilLiaqat I will give it a look! I'm on php for the backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of relying on Blob/CreateObjectURL, try to rely on binary transfer by arrayBuffer as done in https://github.com/Ivan-Feofanov/ws-audio-api.

You'll need also an *encoder* and a _resampler.

**Relevant code to look at**

*https://github.com/Ivan-Feofanov/ws-audio-api/blob/master/src/ws-audio-api.js*

```
Streamer: function(config, socket) {
            navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                navigator.msGetUserMedia);

            this.config = {};
            this.config.codec = this.config.codec || defaultConfig.codec;
            this.config.server = this.config.server || defaultConfig.server;
            this.sampler = new Resampler(44100, this.config.codec.sampleRate, 1, this.config.codec.bufferSize);
            this.parentSocket = socket;
            this.encoder = new OpusEncoder(this.config.codec.sampleRate, this.config.codec.channels, this.config.codec.app, this.config.codec.frameDuration);
            var _this = this;
            this._makeStream = function(onError) {
                navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, function(stream) {
                    _this.stream = stream;
                    _this.audioInput = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                    _this.gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
                    _this.recorder = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(_this.config.codec.bufferSize, 1, 1);
                    _this.recorder.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
                        var resampled = _this.sampler.resampler(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0));
                        var packets = _this.encoder.encode_float(resampled);
                        for (var i = 0; i < packets.length; i++) {
                            if (_this.socket.readyState == 1) _this.socket.send(packets[i]);
                        }
                    };
                    _this.audioInput.connect(_this.gainNode);
                    _this.gainNode.connect(_this.recorder);
                    _this.recorder.connect(audioContext.destination);
                }, onError || _this.onError);
            }
        }
```

**Streaming start**

```
WSAudioAPI.Streamer.prototype.start = function(onError) {
        var _this = this;

        if (!this.parentSocket) {
            this.socket = new WebSocket('wss://' + this.config.server.host + ':' + this.config.server.port);
        } else {
            this.socket = this.parentSocket;
        }

        this.socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

        if (this.socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
            this._makeStream(onError);
        } else if (this.socket.readyState == WebSocket.CONNECTING) {
            var _onopen = this.socket.onopen;
            this.socket.onopen = function() {
                if (_onopen) {
                    _onopen();
                }
                _this._makeStream(onError);
            }
        } else {
            console.error('Socket is in CLOSED state');
        }

        var _onclose = this.socket.onclose;
        this.socket.onclose = function() {
            if (_onclose) {
                _onclose();
            }
            if (_this.audioInput) {
                _this.audioInput.disconnect();
                _this.audioInput = null;
            }
            if (_this.gainNode) {
                _this.gainNode.disconnect();
                _this.gainNode = null;
            }
            if (_this.recorder) {
                _this.recorder.disconnect();
                _this.recorder = null;
            }
            _this.stream.getTracks()[0].stop();
            console.log('Disconnected from server');
        };
    };
```

**Player**

```
WSAudioAPI.Player.prototype.start = function() {
        var _this = this;

        this.audioQueue = {
            buffer: new Float32Array(0),

            write: function(newAudio) {
                var currentQLength = this.buffer.length;
                newAudio = _this.sampler.resampler(newAudio);
                var newBuffer = new Float32Array(currentQLength + newAudio.length);
                newBuffer.set(this.buffer, 0);
                newBuffer.set(newAudio, currentQLength);
                this.buffer = newBuffer;
            },

            read: function(nSamples) {
                var samplesToPlay = this.buffer.subarray(0, nSamples);
                this.buffer = this.buffer.subarray(nSamples, this.buffer.length);
                return samplesToPlay;
            },

            length: function() {
                return this.buffer.length;
            }
        };

        this.scriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(this.config.codec.bufferSize, 1, 1);
        this.scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
            if (_this.audioQueue.length()) {
                e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(_this.audioQueue.read(_this.config.codec.bufferSize));
            } else {
                e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(_this.silence);
            }
        };
        this.gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
        this.scriptNode.connect(this.gainNode);
        this.gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

        if (!this.parentSocket) {
            this.socket = new WebSocket('wss://' + this.config.server.host + ':' + this.config.server.port);
        } else {
            this.socket = this.parentSocket;
        }
        //this.socket.onopen = function () {
        //    console.log('Connected to server ' + _this.config.server.host + ' as listener');
        //};
        var _onmessage = this.parentOnmessage = this.socket.onmessage;
        this.socket.onmessage = function(message) {
            if (_onmessage) {
                _onmessage(message);
            }
            if (message.data instanceof Blob) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function() {
                    _this.audioQueue.write(_this.decoder.decode_float(reader.result));
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(message.data);
            }
        };
        //this.socket.onclose = function () {
        //    console.log('Connection to server closed');
        //};
        //this.socket.onerror = function (err) {
        //    console.log('Getting audio data error:', err);
        //};
      };
```

Comment: this will work with the pusher API? I see from the code that it rely on the websocket API to create a socket. I need also some explainations on how the code works.

Comment: it seems that "binary WebSocket frames are not supported", https://pusher.com/docs/channels/library_auth_reference/pusher-websockets-protocol#websocket-data-messages...if you want to send a stream maybe pusher is not the right spot.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is why I was trying without success to pass the data between the users on the same channel. I will implement my code on a shared hosting service, can you suggest me another service for websocket? Or if possible, a reliable webRTC solution where the socket are used only once for signaling? I don't know if you tested the pusher webRTC demo, but it will not work correctly

Comment: Hi mate, you can use socket.io/ws/sockjs or just use the implementation of library mentioned above

Comment: On a shared hosting it will not work because they don't allow for sockets. This is why initially I choose to use pusher. As a workaroudn, if i compress the data into json? Is it possible ?

Comment: A stream is usually pretty intensive, a shared hosting for the node server is not suitable IMHO, you can search for a specific audio message api service, instead

Comment: I will try with socket.io with the pusher credentials. An experiment I want to do is to compress the data into JSON format and then pass it to the socket connection. Unfortunately I'm using php so I can't apply some of the solutions I've found searching on duckduckgo because are written for node. Thanks for the support, if you have suggestions on how to compress the stream data into JSON please share it.!

Answer (score 0):

Binary data are by far more effective than JSON, I do not recomend to pick that way

Comment: ok, I'm reading about sockjs. For the server part is there any php server library? It's a nice library

Comment: note that even in 2019, this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ratchet php websocket

Or in case you would like to use laravel framework , you can use laravel websockets with Echo