# AudioContext, getUserMedia, and websockets audio streaming

Tags: javascript, audio, websocket, audio-streaming, getusermedia

I am trying to make an as-simple-as-possible Javascript frontend that will allow me to receive audio from a user's mic on a mouse click within a web browser using `getUserMedia`, modify it to a custom sample rate and monochannel, and stream it over a websocket to my server where it will be relayed to Watson Speech API.

I have already built the websocket server using [autobahn](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python). I have been trying to make an updated client library drawing on [whisper](https://github.com/jeff1evesque/whisper) and [ws-audio-api](https://github.com/Ivan-Feofanov/ws-audio-api) but both libraries seem outdated and include much functionality I don't need which I am trying to filter out. I am using [XAudioJS](https://github.com/taisel/XAudioJS) to resample the audio.

**My current progress is in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nathanaeljames/pen/abpGqPv).** I am stuck and having trouble finding more clear examples.

1. Both whisper and ws-audio-api initialize the AudioContext on page load, resulting in an [error](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#webaudio) in at least Chrome and iOS as audio context must now be initialized as a response to user interaction. I have tried to move the AudioContext into the `onClick` event but this results in my having to click twice to begin streaming. I am currently using `audio_context.resume()` within the `onClick` event but this seems like a roundabout solution and results in the page showing it is always recording, even when it's not, which may make my users uneasy. **How can I properly initiate the recording on click and terminate it on click?**
2. I have updated from the deprecated [`Navigator.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) to [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) but not sure if I need to alter the legacy vendor prefixes on lines 83-86 to match the new function?
3. Most importantly, once I get a stream from `getUserMedia`, how can I properly resample it and forward it to the open websocket? I am a bit confused by the structure of bouncing the audio from node to node and I need help with lines 93-108.

Comment: You seem to have both `audio_context` and `audioContext` vars in your code. Possible typos? Oh, and legacy vendor prefixes are a thing of the past in 2021.

Comment: well I initialize `audio_context = new AudioContext` on line 25. Thing of the past in that it should be safe to say few people will have a browser version from 2016?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976084/how-do-i-stream-live-audio-from-the-browser-to-google-cloud-speech-via-socket-io/50976085#50976085) and was able to build a more modern JavaScript frontend based on the code from vin-ni's [Google-Cloud-Speech-Node-Socket-Playground](https://github.com/vin-ni/Google-Cloud-Speech-Node-Socket-Playground) which I tweaked a bit. A lot of the existing audio streaming demos out there in 2021 are either outdated and/ or have a ton of "extra" features which raise the barrier to getting started with websockets and audio streaming. I created this "bare bones" script which reduces the audio streaming down to only four key functions:

1. Open websocket
2. Start Streaming
3. Resample audio
4. Stop streaming

Hopefully this KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid) demo can help somebody else get started with streaming audio a little faster than it took me.

Here is my JavaScript frontend

```js
//================= CONFIG =================
// Global Variables
let websocket_uri = 'ws://127.0.0.1:9001';
let bufferSize = 4096,
    AudioContext,
    context,
    processor,
    input,
    globalStream,
    websocket;

// Initialize WebSocket
initWebSocket();

//================= RECORDING =================
function startRecording() {
    streamStreaming = true;
    AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext({
      // if Non-interactive, use 'playback' or 'balanced' // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContextLatencyCategory
      latencyHint: 'interactive',
    });
    processor = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
    processor.connect(context.destination);
    context.resume();
  
    var handleSuccess = function (stream) {
      globalStream = stream;
      input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      input.connect(processor);
  
      processor.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
        var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        var left16 = downsampleBuffer(left, 44100, 16000);
        websocket.send(left16);
      };
    };
  
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}).then(handleSuccess);
} // closes function startRecording()

function stopRecording() {
    streamStreaming = false;
  
    let track = globalStream.getTracks()[0];
    track.stop();
  
    input.disconnect(processor);
    processor.disconnect(context.destination);
    context.close().then(function () {
      input = null;
      processor = null;
      context = null;
      AudioContext = null;
    });
} // closes function stopRecording()

function initWebSocket() {
    // Create WebSocket
    websocket = new WebSocket(websocket_uri);
    //console.log("Websocket created...");
  
    // WebSocket Definitions: executed when triggered webSocketStatus
    websocket.onopen = function() {
      console.log("connected to server");
      //websocket.send("CONNECTED TO YOU");
      document.getElementById("webSocketStatus").innerHTML = 'Connected';
    }
    
    websocket.onclose = function(e) {
      console.log("connection closed (" + e.code + ")");
      document.getElementById("webSocketStatus").innerHTML = 'Not Connected';
    }
    
    websocket.onmessage = function(e) {
      //console.log("message received: " + e.data);
      console.log(e.data);
  
      try {
        result = JSON.parse(e.data);
      }  catch (e) {
        $('.message').html('Error retrieving data: ' + e);
      }
  
      if (typeof(result) !== 'undefined' && typeof(result.error) !== 'undefined') {
        $('.message').html('Error: ' + result.error);
      }
      else {
        $('.message').html('Welcome!');
      }
    }
} // closes function initWebSocket()

function downsampleBuffer (buffer, sampleRate, outSampleRate) {
    if (outSampleRate == sampleRate) {
      return buffer;
    }
    if (outSampleRate > sampleRate) {
      throw 'downsampling rate show be smaller than original sample rate';
    }
    var sampleRateRatio = sampleRate / outSampleRate;
    var newLength = Math.round(buffer.length / sampleRateRatio);
    var result = new Int16Array(newLength);
    var offsetResult = 0;
    var offsetBuffer = 0;
    while (offsetResult < result.length) {
      var nextOffsetBuffer = Math.round((offsetResult + 1) * sampleRateRatio);
      var accum = 0,
        count = 0;
      for (var i = offsetBuffer; i < nextOffsetBuffer && i < buffer.length; i++) {
        accum += buffer[i];
        count++;
      }
  
      result[offsetResult] = Math.min(1, accum / count) * 0x7fff;
      offsetResult++;
      offsetBuffer = nextOffsetBuffer;
    }
    return result.buffer;
} // closes function downsampleBuffer()
```

And my `index.html` file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
    <script src='client.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='message'>Welcome!</div>
    <button onclick='startRecording()'>Start recording</button>
    <button onclick='stopRecording()'>Stop recording</button>
    <br/>
    <div>WebSocket: <span id="webSocketStatus">Not Connected</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can test this using most of the Autobahn python echo servers which you can find on [Crossbario's GitHub](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo). The `startRecording()` and `stopRecording()` functions could also be called from variables in Storyline or H5P, if one wanted to use this for speech recognition in ed tech (like me).